# Google Cloud: misterious constant 0.033/s compute request APIs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I open a new project on Google Cloud, and I start a default Standard Env App Engine. I don't do anything else, and I start to get mysterious non-zero traffic to my project.

[image]

I specifically keep getting a alternating 0.033/s and 0.017/s request per seconds on the project. This is not specific to this project but to ALL my google cloud projects. Also I get 100% errors rate. I trying to investigate but I didn't even know where to start.

Where can I get more information on what this APIs requests are specifically? And why this happens?

Comment: The API traffic is normal (GCP monitoring your services). However, an error rate of 100% is not normal. Is this error rate 100% of the time, or just when you start a resource such as GCE?

Comment: Was the deployment successful and the service is up and running? Maybe the GCP Monitoring is not reaching the GAE Standard instance due to this. As @JohnHanley said, GCP generates API traffic when monitoring your services.